# Display document according category in HTML

Tags: html, document, categories, categorization

I have one HTML page called "shoes.html" and one html page called "clothes.html". Inside these HTML pages, there are some documents inside a div.

What i want to do is to create a new HTML page, where the visitor of this page would choose if he want to read documents about shoes or clothes. Then according to his selection, the proper document would appear.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This is why you have links in HTML.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Select Clothes or Shoes</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Select what you want to see</h1>
  <p>
    <a href="shoes.html">Go visit shoes</a>
  </p>
  <p>
    <a href="clothes.html">Go visit clothes</a>
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

You have to have your `clothes.html` and `shoes.html` in the same place as this HTML file.